# IE causes css width animation to be reversed

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Relevant parts:

```
#inline-navigation ul {
    display: table;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px 0px;
}

#inline-navigation ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}

#inline-navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
}

#inline-navigation ul li a:after,
#inline-navigation ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6600;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #777;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.1s;
    width: 0;
}

#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(1) a:before,
#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
    right: 0;
    top: -4px;
}

#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(1) a:after,
#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(2) a:after {
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
}

#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(3) a:before,
#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(4) a:before {
    left: 0;
    top: -4px;
}

#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(3) a:after,
#inline-navigation ul li:nth-child(4) a:after {
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 0;
}

#inline-navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff6600;
}

#inline-navigation ul li a:hover:before,
#inline-navigation ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 75%;
}
```

In Internet Explorer 11, the animation produces an extremely bizzare border flicker where the border on the `:after` and `:before` elements seems to escape the parent element(?). I think it's because the animation is played in reverse compared to other browsers.

Fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/NfE87/

Works fine on Chrome and Firefox. Thoughts?

Comment: `<a>` elements are inline by default, and your style has them block in the `:before` and `:after` styles. It looks like IE is having an issue with switching the anchors between the default inline and the block style. when I added `a{display:block;}` to the bottom of the stylesheet it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: note that i commented instead of answered because a) I don't really know what exactly is going on and b) for all I know, making anchors block could screw your layout

Comment: It works! Thanks. I made a very specific rule for the `a` element in the navigation so it doesn't screw the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery animate() function does not work for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525300/jquery-animate-function-does-not-work-for-ie)

Comment: I don't think these two questions share much in common at all. The answers are very different too.

Comment: other than both being related to ie specific css animations, that question shares absolutely nothing in common with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` elements are inline by default, and your style has them block in the `:before` and `:after` styles. It looks like IE is having an issue with switching the anchors between the default inline and the block style. Not sure exactly what that issue is, but...

If you make the anchors block in the stylesheet, the "switching" doesn't happen and it resolves the issue, so just add

`a{display:block;}` to the bottom of the stylesheet. Keep in mind that changing anchors to block elements may affect the layout, so adjust accordingly.